# Get Matrix attributes

Tags: c#, matrix, drawing

I have a `System.Drawing.Drawing2D.Matrix` like the following one:

```
Matrix myMatrix = new Matrix();
myMatrix.Rotate(30);
myMatrix.Scale(1, 2, MatrixOrder.Append);
myMatrix.Translate(5, 0, MatrixOrder.Append);
```

Is there a way to retrieve the rotation angle, the scale and the translation vector?